# Docker container Postgres connection error

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, dockerfile, psql

i have been trying out docker container for postgres. So far i have not been able to connect to the database inside the container.

My steps to recreate the problem below.

**dockerfile start**

```
FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_DB db 
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres
COPY db_schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

I built the docker file like so

```
$ docker build -t db_con .
```

And created a container

```
$ docker run -it -p 5432:5432  --name test_db db_con /bin/bash
```

View of running container as below

```
$ docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID    IMAGE   COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                    NAMES
82347f1114c4    db   "docker-entrypoint..."      3 hours ago    Up 2 sec    0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   test_db
```

I inspected the container for the address info..

```
$ docker inspect test_db

--extract start--
"Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",

                }
            }
--extract end--
```

Now, i have tried within the container, but i have NOT been successful.
I have tried all the commands below with the error below.

```
root@82347f1114c4:/# psql -U postgres -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5432 -d db
root@82347f1114c4:/# psql -U postgres -h 172.17.0.1 -p 5432 -d db
root@82347f1114c4:/# psql -U postgres -h 172.17.0.2 -p 5432 -d db
**response for all the above**
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I will be delighted if anyone can point me in the right direction. I've hit a wall here, any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Try all these stuffs such as creating the schema, connecting to the database instance externally (i.e. outside of the container lifecycle). This is more useful approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you override default postgres cmd to `/bin/bash`.
Why do you put `/bin/bash` at the end of command?

```
docker run -it -p 5432:5432  --name test_db db_con /bin/bash
```

Try to execute

```
docker run -it -p 5432:5432  --name test_db db_con
```

Also, postgres will be available only when db dump was restored.

Comment: Answer right on point, everything working perfectly using your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new rule in your pg_hba.conf:

```
nano /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Add:

```
host    all             all             [Docker Server IP]/16            md5
```

Next, you need to uncomment the follow line in the postgres.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'                  # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

Now restart your postgres service, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

on a separate window / linux term command line:

- **docker exec -it <DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME> bash**      (lands you in Docker shell prompt)
- **psql -U postgres**

should give a postgres=# command prompt

- **postgres=#\l**   (Lists Databases)
- **postgres=#\c my_db**  (connects to my_db database in postgres, akin to USE my_db in MySQL)
- **postgres=#\q**  (quits postgres prompt back to docker shell)